# jenkins : update parameters via groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a text file on server, e.g. /var/lib/jenkins/.../myChoices.txt

```
FirstChoice,SecondChoice
```

As the files will updated from time to time, I want the script update the parameters every time will I click "build with parameters"
But my code only works when I build the job, i.e. is not updating in real time.

```
def getMyChoices() {
    List<String> choices = Arrays.asList(readFileFromWorkspace('/var/lib/jenkins/.../myChoices.txt').split(','))
    return choices
}
job(jobName) {

  description("Deploy something based on choice.")

  parameters {
    ...
    ...
    choiceParam('EB_ACTIVE_ENV_NAME', getMyChoices(), '')
  }
}
```

I do not want to use the hudson plugin too due to some vulnerability reason.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy scripts would be executed only when the job is run. Hence, until the job is run, the parameters would not be refreshed

The only solution available is to this job at regular intervals with an additional flag to refresh the parameters alone and then exit.

This way whenever you click on Build on Parameters options, you will have the latest parameters that exists in the file.

Comment: @Childs your statement is true regarding pipelineDSL. brian661 is using jobDSL

Answer (score 0):

It is required to regenerate the job in order to refresh the parameters.
What I would do is create a job that generates the jobs with jobdsl step when I get a change on the repository where myChoices.txt is versioned

here is an exemple of use of jobDsl

```
    jobDsl removedJobAction: 'DELETE',
            removedViewAction: 'DELETE',
            targets: targetFile,
            unstableOnDeprecation: true,
            additionalParameters: [
                pipelineJobs: arrFiles,
                props: [
                    basePath: destination,
                    gitRemoteUrl: config.gitRemoteUrl,
                    gitConfigJenkinsBranch: config.gitConfigJenkinsBranch,
                    localPath: config.localPath ?: ''
                ]
            ]
```

I use it with a shared library I created that allows me to abstract jobDSL and only write pipelineDSL https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-pipelayer/ but there are restriction to this lib, because I parse the pipelineDSL, getMyChoices() would not be evaluated in the current version of the lib